# On Off Button knockout js

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I was trying to implement a checkbox as on off buttons and I was using this as a example https://jsfiddle.net/meno/MBLP9/ But for some reason the buttons do not appear at all. Here is how the code looks like at my js file.

```
self.on = ko.observable(true);

(function($) {
    ko.bindingHandlers.bootstrapSwitchOn = {
        init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
            $elem = $(element);
            $(element).bootstrapSwitch();
            $(element).bootstrapSwitch('setState', ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor())); // Set intial state
            $elem.on('switch-change', function(e, data) {
                valueAccessor()(data.value);
            }); // Update the model when changed.
        },
        update: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
            var vStatus = $(element).bootstrapSwitch('state');
            var vmStatus = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor());
            if (vStatus != vmStatus) {
                $(element).bootstrapSwitch('setState', vmStatus);
            }
        }
    };
})(jQuery);
```

And in my html file

```
<p class="pushBasket">  
   <span data-bind="text: on() ? 'on' : 'off'"></span>
   <span class="pullBasketRight"><input type="checkbox"  data-bind="bootstrapSwitchOn: on"/></span>
</p>
```

in my html file, this < p > tag is inside a foreach databinding , so it might also cause the buttons not to appear I guess.

Here is the whole html code 
http://pastebin.com/csWRfgS8

Comment: @KWeiss did not understand what you meant, do you mean what my foreach provides?

Comment: @KWeiss its basically a table, which is showing data from the database, and one part of the row has this extra p tag with this checkbox, but not coming from the foreach

Comment: It is inside the foreach.

Comment: @KWeiss i also tried the code outside foreach , it does not work

Comment: Can you paste the full code with the foreach, and what exactly are you using in the foreach an array with which values?

Comment: @ddiestra I guess for each does not matter for now, since I am trying the code on a completly empty html page, it still does not work.

Comment: dumb question, are you loading all the libraries that example use? https://jsfiddle.net/meno/MBLP9/

Comment: @ddiestra yes, loading all of them, I tried copying the other codes from the github account as well

Comment: @KWeiss 
here is the paste bin for the whole foreach array 
http://pastebin.com/csWRfgS8 Let me know if you want the js code as well

Comment: @ddiestra 
here is the paste bin for the whole foreach array 
http://pastebin.com/csWRfgS8 Let me know if you want the js code as well

Comment: The pastebin doesn't help too much, on SO it's preferred to have *all* relevant (yet *as little as possible*) code to repro the issue in the question itself. See [mcve] for guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks fine

Just use `$root.on` and remove `<span data-bind="text: on() ? 'on' : 'off'"></span>`

That should work hopefully.